# Uploading multiple interdependent packages to CRAN

Tags: r, package, cran

I am preparing three R packages to soon upload to CRAN which are interdependent. Specifically, package `A` is already on CRAN and to be updated, package `B` is independent and package `C` depends on both the latest versions of `A` and `B`.

I could do this without having problems in checks by first uploading `A` and `C` and uploading `B` a few days later. But, I would like to immediately put crossreferences in the help pages and add all packages to each other's suggest list. Additionally, since I will develop all three further, I would like to be able to update them in the future at the same time.

So, the question here is, is it possible to upload multiple interdependent packages to CRAN at the same time? How could I do that?

Comment: What is the reason for keeping it as three separate packages if they are so interdependent? Asking out of curiosity.

Comment: In your DESCRIPTION you can put depends statements that require not only a package but a particular version of that package. From R-exts: `The package name may be optionally followed by a comment in parentheses. The comment should contain a comparison operator, whitespace and a valid version number.`  Perhaps this is a way around your issue.

Comment: They do read the e-mail that you send when you upload a package.  Couldn't you explain it there?  Or, send an e-mail ahead of time and ask?

Comment: yes, CRAN is not a robot; they always try to give personal, meaningful feedback when a submission fails. If you describe the situation no doubt they'll accomodate, provided there are no other issues.

Comment: Send CRAN an email first and ask for their suggestions. Better to be up front and not waste their time. They'll appreciate it. But do make sure you've availed yourself of all the documentation and guidelines first.

Comment: @EricFail They each are for distinctly different purposes. I like to make smaller packages with a clear intent for each rather than a large package where functions might get lost / hidden in.

@ others. Thanks. I know there are real humans working at CRAN :) I also know they are extremely busy so I rather not waste their time too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Been there done that this week (with a `Depends:` on a version of `xts` that arrived yesterday).  And we do that within `Rcpp*` a lot too.

So just use versioned Depends:

- update A to provide version 42
- upload B to provide its initial version 0.0.7
- upload C with `Depends: A (>= 42), B (>= 0.0.7)`
- now update A version 42.1 with `Suggests:` for B and C

The Fine Manual is pretty clear about it, and carried all these semantics over from Debian where they were refined since the mid-1990s.

Comment: But, then after uploading C, he has to update A and B to include Suggests: C